# How do I change three-dimensional array to single-dimentional array(PHP)

Tags: php

I have a three dimensional array. I want to right a function to transform it to a single dimensional array and keep the previous sub-key. How do I do that?

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
   array(2) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "4"
     ["assignedlessons"]=>
     string(2) "69"
   }
  [1]=>
   array(2) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "4"
     ["assignedlessons"]=>
     string(3) "308"
   }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
   array(2) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "10"
     ["assignedlessons"]=>
     string(2) "50"
   }
  [1]=>
   array(2) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "10"
     ["assignedlessons"]=>
     string(2) "91"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to transform it to the structure like this one:

```
   array(0) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "4"
     ["assignedlessons"]=>
     string(2) "69"
   }

   array(1) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "4"
     ["assignedlessons"]=>
     string(3) "308"
   }

   array(2) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "10"
     ["assignedlessons"]=>
     string(2) "50"
   }
   array(3) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "10"
     ["assignedlessons"]=>
     string(2) "91"
    }
```

What I have is this function:

```
function toSingleDimentionalArray($array){
 $final = array();
 foreach($array as $value){
   foreach($array as $key => $val){
      $final[]['id'] = $val['id'];  
      $final[]['assignedlessons'] = $val['assignedlessons'];
    }

 }
 return $final;
}
```

But it only return something like this:

```
array(19648) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
 string(1) "4"
}
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
  ["assignedlessons"]=>
  string(2) "69"
}
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
  ["assignedlessons"]=>
  string(3) "308"
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is pretty straight-forward looping, and shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: Have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+flatten+array

Comment: Your intended result is not a single dimensional array

Comment: Note that `array(3)` means "An array of length 3". Next time, use `print_r()` to debug variable contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
function toNotActuallyASingleDimensionalArray($array) {
    $final = array();
    foreach($array as $subarray) {
        foreach($subarray as $val) {
            $final[] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $final;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$final_array = array();

foreach($array as $sub_array)
{
  foreach($sub_array as $temp_array)
  {
    $final_array[] = $temp_array;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function simplify_array($array, $first_level=true) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $last_level = !is_array($value);
        if($last_level) {
            return $array;
        }else if($first_level) {
            $return[] = simplify_array($value, false);
        }else{
            return simplify_array($value, false);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}


print_r(simplify_array($arr));
```

HTH

it will work for n-dimensional arrays